# Showing [object Object] in embed footer

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed, footer, replit

SEE THIS PIC:
[image: SEE THIS PIC]

> I have given the codes which I tried.

> If I don't add `iconURL` then it works fine (ONLY FYI).

> I am using discord.js v13.

**CODE 1**

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Thanks for Boosting <a:gifland_boost:810489455805857833>")
        .setURL(`https://discord.com/channels/948465967862784070/959091641577246770`)
        .setDescription(`Congratulations, you've got 20 coins to add projects in uptimer bot.\n Add one using: \`,add <url>\`\nCheck Coins: \`,balance\``)
        .setFooter({ text: `Send From [${newMember.guild.name}]` , iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/oO5ZSRK.png'})
        .setColor("#ff52bf");
```

**CODE 2**

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Thanks for Boosting <a:gifland_boost:810489455805857833>")
        .setURL(`https://discord.com/channels/948465967862784070/959091641577246770`)
        .setDescription(`Congratulations, you've got 20 coins to add projects in uptimer bot.\n Add one using: \`,add <url>\`\nCheck Coins: \`,balance\``)
        .setFooter({ text: `Send From [${newMember.guild.name}]` , iconURL: newMember.guild.icon})
        .setColor("#ff52bf");
```

> i did some experiments and i got to know that the problem is not in `iconURL` ,the problem is in `text`
> my theory - i removed `iconURL` and just kept the `text` and when i checked , the problem exist but when i removed `text` also , the problem gets solved so this means that the problem is in `text` and not in `iconURL` or `proxyIconURL`

Comment: If you use code 1 does it work?

Comment: Are both codes not working?

Comment: guild.icon returns icon hash in a string use `iconURL()` instead. [check here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=iconURL)
in CODE 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in `iconURL`. I wrote `newMember.guild.icon` which was returning a hash but for `footer.iconURL` it requires a URL. So the solution is `newMember.guild.iconURL()` which will return a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using: 
`` .setFooter({ text: `Send From [${newMember.guild.name}]` , iconURL: newMember.guild.icon}) ``

Use: 
`` .setFooter(`Send From [${newMember.guild.name}]`, newMember.guild.icon}) ``

Check out source code of discord.js here[discord.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js#L431)
This should work.

Comment: Nope that's wrong the error is in iconURL, it is returning a hash and not a url